# aspx page asks me to open or save in all the browsers

Tags: asp.net, iis

I run IIS 8 on the server and configured my application to run in 4.0 in pipeline mode: integrated and added the mime type to add .aspx extension and whenever i try to view my .aspx pages, the browsers asks me to open or save the file. But the html files open up without any issues.

I have no clue why i am not able to open my .aspx pages.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue - I am not sure whether this would apply to others, but i created a new website in VS2010, unlike i did as a project, earlier, and copied all my files, except the web.config into this newly created website and then created a new virtual directory in IIS 8 and mapped the folder in wwwroot and converted that to an application and now, my IIS serves the .aspx pages without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to add a custom MIME type to serve an ASPX file.  What MIME type did you use?  What happens if you delete that?

Comment: sorry for such a late response @dave Mroz actually, i think the issue was in the way i created the project,,,i should have created as a website in VS2010, and created a new virtual directory in IIS 8 and mapped the folder in wwwroot and converted that to an application and voila! my .aspx pages show up. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS8, you should not add MIME for ASPX pages as it is clearly stated in the error itself, that do not add MIME for ASPX or any any other page that you do not want to download. In the solution (in IIS8) is to check Application Server.
[image]